# Model of Arithmetic concept for usage as Opaque typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a type that models the Arithmetic concept and use it as an opaque `typedef` (AKA strong `typedef`, see Note below) in some projects.

I've put the code into [its own repository](https://github.com/gnzlbg/arithmetic_type) along with some tests and would like some eyes taking a look into it.

**Note:** for opaque `typedef` I understand the definition given in [N3515](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3515.pdf).

- Prior art exist in `Boost.Serialization` [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html), where it seems that the opaque `typedef`s created model the Arithmetic concept (it is thought to be used for integers) but:

  - This is not clearly stated
  - It doesn't support C++11 features like `constexpr`, and move semantics
  - It does not inhibit implicit conversions
- On implicit conversions: I wanted to allow conversions, but prefer them to be explicit. This could be made configurable but I don't think it is worth the trouble.

Some examples of usage:

- Example 1: disabling implicit conversions

  ```
  int a{2};
  long b{3};
  b = a; // works: the implicit conversion is safe

  Arithmetic<int> a{2};
  Arithmetic<long> b{3};
  b = a; // error: implicit assignment requires implicit conversion
  b = Arithmetic<long>{a};               // works: explicit construction
  b = static_cast<Arithmetic<long>>(a);  // works: explicit conversion
  ```
- Example 2: opaque type-defs

  ```
  struct Tag1 {};
  struct Tag2 {};

  using Type1 = Arithmetic<int, Tag1>;
  using Type2 = Arithmetic<int, Tag2>;
  Type1 a{2};
  Type2 b{3};
  b = Type2{a};               // works: explicit construction
  b = static_cast<Type2>(a);  // works: explicit conversion
  Type2 c{a};                 // works: explicit construction
  ```

**arithmetic_type.hpp:**

```
#ifndef BOOST_UTILITIES_ARITHMETIC_TYPE_ARITHMETIC_TYPE_
#define BOOST_UTILITIES_ARITHMETIC_TYPE_ARITHMETIC_TYPE_
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
namespace boost {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// \name Index types
///@{
/// \brief Implements an integer type
template <class T, class B = void> struct Arithmetic {
  using value_type = T;
  using type = T;

  /// \name Asignment operators
  ///@{
  constexpr Arithmetic() noexcept(T{T{}}) : value{T{}} {}
  constexpr Arithmetic(const Arithmetic& other) noexcept(T{T{}})
    : value{other.value} {}
  constexpr Arithmetic(Arithmetic&& other) noexcept(T{T{}})
    : value{other.value} {}
  constexpr explicit Arithmetic(const T& other) noexcept(T{T{}})
    : value{other} {}
  template <class U, class V>
  constexpr explicit Arithmetic(const Arithmetic<U, V>& other) noexcept(T{T{}})
    : value(other.value) {}

  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator=(const Arithmetic& other) noexcept {
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator=(Arithmetic&& other) noexcept {
    value = other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator=(const T& other) noexcept {
    value = other;
    return *this;
  }
  ///@}

  /// \name Conversion operators
  ///@{
  explicit constexpr inline operator T() noexcept { return value; }
  explicit constexpr inline operator const T() const noexcept { return value; }

  template <class U, class V>
  explicit constexpr inline operator Arithmetic<U, V>() noexcept {
    return value;
  }

  template <class U, class V>
  explicit constexpr inline operator const Arithmetic<U, V>() const noexcept {
    return value;
  }
  ///@}

  /// \name Compound assignment +=, -=, *=, /=
  ///@{
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator+=(const Arithmetic& other) noexcept {
    value += other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator-=(const Arithmetic& other) noexcept {
    value -= other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator*=(const Arithmetic& other) noexcept {
    value *= other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator/=(const Arithmetic& other) noexcept {
    value /= other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  ///@}

  /// \name Arithmetic operators +,-,*,/,unary -
  ///@{
  constexpr friend inline Arithmetic operator+(Arithmetic a,
                                               const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a += b;
  }
  constexpr friend inline Arithmetic operator-(Arithmetic a,
                                               const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a -= b;
  }
  constexpr friend inline Arithmetic operator*(Arithmetic a,
                                               const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a *= b;
  }
  constexpr friend inline Arithmetic operator/(Arithmetic a,
                                               const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a /= b;
  }

  constexpr inline Arithmetic operator-() noexcept {
    static_assert(std::is_signed<T>::value, "Can't negate an unsigned type!");
    return Arithmetic{-value};
  }
  ///@}

  /// \name Prefix increment operators ++(),--()
  ///@{
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator++() noexcept {
    ++value;
    return *this;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic& operator--() noexcept {
    --value;
    return *this;
  }
  ///@}

  /// \name Postfix increment operators ()++,()--
  ///@{
  constexpr inline Arithmetic operator++(int) noexcept {
    Arithmetic tmp(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
  }
  constexpr inline Arithmetic operator--(int) noexcept {
    Arithmetic tmp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return tmp;
  }
  ///@}

  /// \name Comparison operators ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=
  ///@{
  constexpr friend inline bool operator==(const Arithmetic& a,
                                          const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a.value == b.value;
  }
  constexpr friend inline bool operator<=(const Arithmetic& a,
                                          const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a.value <= b.value;
  }
  constexpr friend inline bool operator<(const Arithmetic& a,
                                         const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return a.value < b.value;
  }  // return a <= b && !(a == b) -> slower?
  constexpr friend inline bool operator!=(const Arithmetic& a,
                                          const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return !(a == b);
  }
  constexpr friend inline bool operator>(const Arithmetic& a,
                                         const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return !(a <= b);
  }
  constexpr friend inline bool operator>=(const Arithmetic& a,
                                          const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
    return !(a < b);
  }
  ///@}

  /// \brief swap
  constexpr friend inline void swap(Arithmetic&& a, Arithmetic&& b) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.value, b.value);
  }

  /// \name Access operator
  ///@{
  constexpr inline T& operator()() & noexcept { return value; }
  constexpr inline T operator()() && noexcept { return value; }
  constexpr inline T operator()() const& noexcept { return value; }
  ///@}

  /// Data (wrapped value):
  T value;
};
///@}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}  // namespace boost
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace std {

template <class T, class B>
class numeric_limits<boost::Arithmetic<T, B>> : public numeric_limits<T> {
 public:
  static const bool is_specialized = true;
};

}  // namespace std

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif  // BOOST_UTILITIES_ARITHMETIC_TYPE_ARITHMETIC_TYPE_
```

Furthermore, there is a `to_string` overload as well as `istream` / `ostream` operators in other header files. The rationale is, those who don't need them, shouldn't pay for `<string>`/`<istream>`/`<ostream>`.

Comment: I am no expert on arithmetic types so I might be mistaken, but wouldn't it be better to forward each `operator` to the exact same one on the underlying type?

Comment: What is the `class B = void` template parameter used for? I don't see `B` being used anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisW I've added two examples that show how the class should be used.

Comment: @Nobody if the type models the arithmetic concept this is not needed for all operators, just for some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some small things you can improve:

- `constexpr inline` isn't necessary: `constexpr` already implies `inline`.
- In the following function:

  ```
  constexpr friend inline Arithmetic operator+(Arithmetic a,
                                               const Arithmetic& b) noexcept {
      return a += b;
  }
  ```

  The `friend` keyword isn't useful: the only function you are calling is `operator+=` which is `public`. This note holds for all your `operator@=` and for all the operators that do not use `private` members.
- `operator<=`, `operator>` and `operator>=` are generally implemented in function of `operator<`. A decent level of optimization should get rid of what you seem to consider a overhead.
- The following member should be `constexpr`, not `const`:

  ```
  static const bool is_specialized = true;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Made all the improvements already. Since value is a public data member, I guess I can make all operators that do not need to be class members non-friend non-member functions.

Comment: @gnzlbg Well, you can do that. I don't know whether `value` being `public` is a good idea though; I don't really have an opinion on that question.

Comment: Neither do I. It seemed irrelevant so I left it public to avoid complicating the life of those who want to explicitly avoid the type-safety offered by the class.

Comment: @gnzlbg Then, what are the `operator()()` overloads for? They are kind of redundant if `value` is already `public` :/

Comment: They are for lazy people, 3 keystrokes less... no kidding.

Comment: @gnzlbg You could have made them `explicit operator value_type()` overload instead. I find it more explicit (haha) than using `operator()()` which I wouldn't intuitively use to get the underlying value.

Comment: What do you mean? I have an `explicit constexpr operator T() noexcept` but that forces you to do an e.g. `static_cast<T>(...)`. I hope I left all doors open to make getting the underlying value as easy as possible.

Comment: @gnzlbg Oops. I overooked that one. My bad.

Comment: thanks a lot for your input! I think it has significantly improved the class (commits are on github!).